# Elementor Showing CSS Code in Fontend, Why?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[Elementor Showing CSS Code in Fontend. How Can handle it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOWpx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually not CSS code. It is a shortcode of a different plugin (which is not active on your Wordpress)

I think [pl_row] shortcode belongs to the page builder called [Page Layer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagelayer/). If you install and active it, your page will display content.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Mehedi Hasan Rooman

You haven't activated some dependent plugins, that's why it is showing like above screenshot.

Steps to activate WordPress plugins:

1. Login to your WordPress Admin.
   Navigate to the Plugins and click on the activate link to activate the Elementor plugins.